# Import products via SOAP and reuse the same image for all products

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images, soap

I've created a script to import many hundred products from another datasource via SOAP to magento but I want to use the same product image for all products.
Is this possible?

Comment: do you want to import one image same for all products ?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Place your product image at /media/import/folder. and rest code will handle

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://yourmagentohost.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('yourapiusername','yourapipassword');
$name = $product->getName()
$download_path = "/home/magento/media/imports/" . $file_name; // path to media/import/
$content = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
$newFile = array(
    'content' => $content,
    'mime' => 'image/jpeg'
);
$client->catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate(
    $session, $productId, array('file' => $newFile, 'label' => $name, 'position' => '50', 'types' => array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), 'exclude' => 0)
);
```

Comment: Thanks but with this solution the same image will be upload again for each product, right? is it possible that all of the products have the same img path?